# What is the proper location of properties files for a java web service?

Tags: java, web-services, standards, properties-file

This question isn't in regards to how to get/read the properties files, but instead what is the standard or accepted location to keep them. Specifically, I've got two types of properties, one that is sort of a server config file and a couple that are written to and read from to contain information sent to/from a client. So where should these be placed?

Comment: Why you want store dynamic data from clients in properties files? Probably using of database for this purpose a better option.

Comment: @alexey28 The constraints of the project do not allow for a database, unfortunately.

Comment: Then Dave post is what you need - place server properties file in classpath and client properties in some external place to have possibility change it and do not override with every deployment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you see as the options?

Config files should be on the classpath, unless they need to be trivially modifiable. If they do, then they should be in a location external to the app, and the location set by either default, a JNDI string, a system property, or whatever.

Files that are regularly updated as part of system operation *must* be external, and configured in the same way. Although I'd question whether or not it makes sense to do that kind of persistence with a file.